# Multiplying double variable by double in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm making in app that includes a user entering the price of an object, and the app outputs the price including tax. However, every time it outputs 0, and I get a run-time error involving the variable, myDouble. I'm trying to take the value put in a text field and multiplying it by 1.06 (I'm starting out with a set tax rate), and then setting a label to the new value. Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    NSString *myString = inputtext2.text;
    double myDouble = [myString doubleValue];
    myDouble = myDouble*1.06;
    NSLog(@"myDouble: %lf", myDouble);
    price.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", myDouble];
}
```

Comment: This is the error: 2012-08-01 10:07:57.359 PursePals2[541:f803] myDouble: 0.000000

Comment: It comes up when I hit enter after putting in the price

Comment: Oh..But shouldn't the variable be equal to what the user puts in the text field?

Comment: fixed it. thanks for the hint

Comment: You will still benefit from using the number formatter and protecting from unexpected entry. Additionally you can use it to localize your formatted input/output style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your inputtext2 variable is nil, so it is returning nothing. If this is an outlet, check the connections in interface builder. If the outlet is not connected, the variable will be `nil`, so the string value will be `nil`, so the double value will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to want to use a NSNumberFormatter and check for valid entry.

pseudo code, uncompiled:

```
-(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    NSString *myString = inputtext2.text;    
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber *myNumber = [formatter numberFromString: myString];
    double myDouble = 0;
    if (myNumber != nil) {
      myDouble = [myNumber doubleValue];
    }

    NSString *outputString = [formatter stringFromNumber:myDouble];
    price.text = outputString;
}
```

This should default your number to 0 if the text entered is 0 or not a valid number.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I get three errors from this code: ARC forbids explicit message send of autorelease, autorelease is unavailable: not available in ARC mode, and sending NSNumber *_strong to incompatible type double. Is there some little thing I need to change/import to make this all work?

Comment: Wouldn't it be hilarious if I hadn't linked the variable inputtext2 to the text field on the storyboard? Explains why inputtext2.text was always set to nil. Everything's working fine now

Comment: oops, old habit. That is what happens when I take off the training wheels. Should be able to delete the autorelease is all.

Comment: Sam, I did edit and it should work now. I can't tell you how many times I chased a mysterious issue and came to the same realization that the outlets were not connected. +1 to @jrturton for going right to the simplest and most likely cause.